# convert binary and save this to video format on php language

Tags: php

I try an API to get video content. The problem is, the return of the api is binary. How can I get a video file?

When I want to get an image, I just run this code:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$aa = base64_encode($response);

$data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$aa;

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('image2.jpg', $data);
```

but I think it doesn't work when I want to convert into video.